# Get the new PHPSESSID from file_get_contents result (PHP)

Tags: php, session, cookies, file-get-contents

So http://example.com/test.php generates a PHP Session cookie for the client.

So I do

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com/test.php");
```

But it returns me only the HTML source (no headers).

How do I get the PHPSESSID that was set by that page? I don't want to use CURL or addons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic variable  `$http_response_header` for that.

Use it this way:

```
file_get_contents("http://example.com");
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Find more information in the php manual for [http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php).